# Python: Convert quote in HTML content not HTML tags

Tags: python, html, regex, mindtouch

I have a piece of HTML like this:

```
<pre class="script">template("main/GlobalShared");</pre>
<pre class="script">
var link = '/Draft/Tracker_1.1';
if (wiki.pageexists(link)) {
    &lt;div class="version"&gt; web.link(wiki.uri(link), 'Version 1.1') &lt;/div&gt;
}
</pre>
```

I need to convert it like this:

```
<pre class="script">template(&quot;main/GlobalShared&quot;);</pre>
<pre class="script">
var link = '/Draft/Tracker_1.1';
if (wiki.pageexists(link)) {
    &lt;div class=&quot;version&quot;&gt; web.link(wiki.uri(link), 'Version 1.1') &lt;/div&gt; 
}
</pre>
```

I have been fiddling with regular expressions but I can't seem to get even close.
I think my choice is completely wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction if this is even possible?

Comment: You should use a DOM parser (I think [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is good in Python) and then traverse the text nodes of the DOM to only do the replacement there. With regex alone you won't be able to do it reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a HTML parser instead, then simply replace the quotes with `.replace('"', '&quot;')`.

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) makes this task easy:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource)

for string in soup.strings:
     string.replace_with(string.replace('"', '&quot;'))

htmlsource = str(soup)
```

Comment: I just noticed that it converts quote to &amp;quot;. Got any ideas why?

Comment: Ah, because assigning to text in the BeautifulSoup tree auto-quotes it the string. `&` is replaced by `&amp;` because that is the correct action to take.

Comment: **Reading** the text will give you `&quot;` again as the ampersand is to be unquoted automatically by anything reading the DOM text.

Comment: It is only in the source HTML text that you see `&amp;quot;`.

Comment: I have a WX App that reads the HTML from a TextCtrl, has to fix that quot issue and then prepend or append it to some HTML it GET via an API and PUT the result to the API. The API will not accept &amp;quot;.

Comment: @tntu: Why doesn't the API accept `"` then? Either the API reads HTML text and decodes it, or it accepts raw HTML without decoding and the quotes just work.

Comment: Cause it is not regular HTML it also contains a custom scripting language. If I post with quote or with &amp;quot; it does not interpret the script right. I didn't build it.

Comment: I think that if you use the XML mode it'll do the right thing; let me test.